# C# DirectoryNotFound Error When Copying FIles

Tags: c#, file, copy

I just wanted to see if anyone else got this issue. 
I am trying to copy files from one directory to another, however when it gets to a file copy such as this:

```
//copy each file
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
```

It gives me an error such as "DirectoryNotFound" Exception. Even though the directory exists. 
Has anyone run into this problem and what would a good solution around it be?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have permissions on that directory.....

Comment: The directory is on my c:\ so I find that impossible.

Comment: The path must be wrong, I think there no other reason why a DirectoryNotFound Exception would trigger.

Comment: Which throws the exception ? `Directory.GetFiles()` or `File.Copy()`?

Comment: Modern Windows will not let you write directly to C:/ by default so your expectations may be skewed. You might have it configured otherwise, in which case I'd recommend to revert that.

Comment: You are certain that `targetDir` is not a full path to something?  And that it's not a protected directory?  Being on `C:` doesn't automatically make it accessible, you know.

Comment: The path is not entered manually, therefore there it would be hard for it to be wrong.

Comment: It's a constant like `String targetDir = "C:\notagoodpath";`?

Comment: From the documentation:  `The path specified in sourceFileName or destFileName is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).`  Not much grey area.

Comment: How exactly are sourceDir and targetDir defined? Source code please :)

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson this program is essentially copying files from one directory to another, the path of the files aren't entered at all in the program, they are simply kept in an external XML file where the paths are stored. The program will search through the source and destination paths for certain files to copy files.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson ...Continued 

So either way they arent entered anywhere except for the XML file and when building the paths I essentially did a copy/paste of the paths from the windows explorer path bar into the XML file. So there isn't a way for them to be invalid since other than that they arent entered anywhere.
The sourceDir and targetDir are the source and destination paths which are retrieved from the xml file. 
Unless there is a way to copy all files from one to another flawlessly that would great!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson make sure you're using double slash like "c:\\path" or @"c:\path"

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo There was a reason for the path name :)

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo Indeed, a double slash is being used.

Comment: I figured out whats going on with it, it's the way the files are being copied over, its trying to copy a subdirectory over as a file... So i'm searching up a way how to just copy everything over.